# Scaling/Moving doesn't work properly

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, mirror

recently I decided to learn and use Blender as my 3D editor

Well, all this things were working fine... until a few minutes

I made a mirrored object, but, when I press the "S" scale button, doesn't scale me proportionally

[image]

And the same thing with the "G" move button, it moves weird

[image]

And no, I didn't press the X/Y/Z keys to align it to the axes while scaling/moving

What did I do wrong or how can I return it to normal?

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by normal.. The object is mirrored. So not all mesh is edited but only real geometry which is shown with yellow color and that geometry will scale as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior with the mirror modifier.

You have the *clipping* checkbox selected on the modifier, which means that any vertices that are on the mirror plane get stuck to that plane, and can only move along it, not off of it. To disable this sticking behaviour, you can just uncheck the clipping box.

However, scaling /moving etc will still only move the actual vertices you are editing, not the virtual ones created by the modifier.